# Avoid animation reload on am charts

Tags: javascript, css, animation, amcharts

I'd like to know if there is any way to avoid animation reload for the entire graph every time a user click on any of the graph variables.

I've got a graph with 3 lines css animated and i would like to keep the existing lines without animate it again if I add a new variable to the graph.

```
Here is the graph:
```

https://codepen.io/figu78/pen/QvepyM

Well, i want to keep the line animation. What i don't want is to redraw every single line, every time I add a new line.

I mean, if the green line (50SRU) is already in the graph, when I click on the yellow line (150SRU) I don't want to redraw green line again, only yellow line should do the animation.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would do that by setting the [startDuration](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#startDuration) to 0, but since it is already 0, you only have to change your CSS. You have to remove:

```
  -webkit-animation: am-draw 10s;
  animation: am-draw 10s;
```

That way you won't have any animations with the graph.

Comment: I want to keep line animations but avoid graph reload when someone clicks on legend. Only do the animation on the new line.